# radio button value being sent as “on” in React

Tags: reactjs

I have custom FormInput component like this:

> ```
> import React from "react";
>
> import {
>   GroupContainer,
>   FormInputContainer,
>   FormInputLabel,
>   FormInputIcon,
> } from "./formInput.styles";
>
> interface FormInputProps {
>   onChange?: (event: React.SyntheticEvent) => void;
>   label: string;
>   value?: any;
>   checkbox?: boolean;
>   radioBtn?: boolean;
>   name: "name" | "email" | "password" | "gender" | "country";
>   type: "password" | "email" | "text" | "radio" | "checkbox";
>   required: boolean;
>   checked?: boolean;
>   emailIcon?: string;
>   passwordIcon?: string;
> }
>
> const FormInput = ({
>   onChange,
>   label,
>   value,
>   emailIcon,
>   passwordIcon,
>   ...props
> }: FormInputProps) => (
>   <GroupContainer {...props}>
>     <FormInputContainer onChange={onChange} {...props} />
>     {label ? (
>       <FormInputLabel
>         {...props}
>         // className={value && value.length ? "shrink" : ""}
>       >
>         {emailIcon && <FormInputIcon  src={emailIcon} />}
>         {passwordIcon && <FormInputIcon passwordIcon={passwordIcon} src={passwordIcon} />}
>         {label}
>       </FormInputLabel>
>     ) : null}
>   </GroupContainer>
> );
>
> export default FormInput;
> ```

Then I use that component as the following:

```
<GenderContainer onChange={handleChange}>
          <FormInput
            type="radio"
            name="gender"
            value="Male"
            // checked={gender}
            label="Male"
            radioBtn={true}
            required
          />
          <FormInput
            type="radio"
            name="gender"
            value="Female"
            // checked={gender}
            label="Female"
            radioBtn={true}
            required
          />
        </GenderContainer>
```

But the problem is when I change value of radio buttons then radio buttons's value is "on". I have also checked this [radio button value being sent as "on" upon form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577484/radio-button-value-being-sent-as-on-upon-form-submission) but I pas value prop as it is instead of val or something like that. Pls help

Comment: @t3__rry, I have tried those ways, but I dunno the problem still remains. Pls do you have any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: Could you share your `onChange`  / `handleChange` function definition?

Comment: @t3__rry, here, const handleChange = (event: any) => {
    // const { name, value } = event.target;

    dispatch({ field: event.target.name, value: event.target.value });

    console.log(event.target.value);

    // this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };

Comment: @t3__rry, I am using useReducer thus the above code uses dispatch

Comment: Are you sure your `value` prop is set to the input?

Comment: @t3__rry, ha ha you are right I forgot to pass value prop). You saved my day) many thanks  dude